# Debugging a recursive while loop (php)

Tags: php, algorithm, recursion, while-loop, mustache

I'm writing a function to take the tags from a mustache template and generate a hash (the reason for this is to be able to take any given template and quickly show a developer what the expected variables are).

I extract the tags into a flat array (easy enough), but the next step is tricky - I need to turn the flat array into a multi-dimensional array to indicate nested variable.

Here's my sample flat array:

```
$arr = array(
  'one',
  '#two',
  'sub1',
  'sub2',
  '/two',
  'three'
);
```

And the expected output:

```
$newArray = array(
  'one'=>'',
  'two'=>array(
    'sub1'=>'',
    'sub2'=>''
   ),
   'three'=>''
  );
```

I have been getting close, but am not quite there yet. I thought a recursive function would be the way to go (though I am open to a different solution). Here is what I have so far:

```
function recurse($array, $i = 0) {
  $nested = array();

  while ($i < count($array)):
    $tag = $array[$i];

    if (preg_match('/\//',$tag)) {
      return $nested;
    } elseif (preg_match('/^#/',$tag)) {
      $tag = str_replace('#','',$tag);
      $nested[$tag] = recurse($array, $i+1);
      $i+= count($nested[$tag])+1;
    } else {
      $nested[$tag] = '';
      $i++;
    }
  endwhile;
  return $nested;
}
```

I think the bug may be that it hits the first 'if' and returns all the way out of the function, but I'm not certain, nor am I sure how to fix it.

Comment: What is the result you are currently seeing?

Comment: It only builds it as far as 'sub2'

Comment: I don't think it hits `if(preg_match('/\/', $tag))` it gives me an error about it also (warning);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified your function a bit to match your needs, see if it works for you:

```
$arr = array(
  'one',
  '#two',
    'sub1',
    '#sub2',
        'subsub1',
        'subsub2',
        'subsub3',
        'subsub4',
    '/sub2',
    'sub3',
  '/two',
  'three'
);

function recurse($array, &$i, $current_tag = "") 
{
    $nested = array();

    while ($i < count($array)):
        $tag = $array[$i];
        if ($tag == '/'.$current_tag) 
        {
            $i++;
            return $nested;
        } 
        elseif (preg_match('/^#/',$tag)) 
        {
            $tag = str_replace('#','',$tag);
            $i++;
            $nested[$tag] = recurse($array, $i, $tag);
        } else 
        {
            $nested[$tag] = '';
            $i++;
        }
    endwhile;
    return $nested;
}

$i = 0;
$a = recurse($arr, $i);

echo '<pre>'.print_r($a, true).'</pre>';
```

You had some issues with that $i... I gave it as reference so that it will automatically update with the function system, and used another parameter to match exactly the next closing tag..., so that it will validate.

Comment: Having the $i as the reference looks to be the missing piece. I need to get a better handle on passing values as reference - I don't do it often and the concept is a bit hazy to me (esp when involved with recursion).

Comment: @PhilipSchweiger , I'm glad it helped you, you had another problem although: you didn't checked if your closing tag matched the last opening tag, in consequence any closing tag would have ended your subtree parsing.

Comment: I'm going to add this as a the core of a new method to Mustache.php and send a pull request - I'll note your contribution in my code.

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun I decided to make you one **without recursion** and using references instead (more efficient that recursion, storing array element aliases on a stack). Works with nested subsets too.

```
$arr = array(
    'one',
        '#two','sub1',
            '#twotwo','sub1','sub2','/twotwo',  
        'sub2','/two',
    'three'
);

$out = array();

$stack = array();
$sp = 0;

$stack[$sp] = &$out;

foreach ($arr as $item) {
    $cur =& $stack[$sp];
    if ($item[0] == '#') {
        $item = substr($item, 1);
        $cur[$item] = array();
        $stack[++$sp] = &$cur[$item];
    }
    elseif ($item[0] == '/') {
        $sp--;
    }
    else {
        $cur[] = $item;
    }
}
var_dump($out);
```

Output:

```
array
  0 => string 'one' (length=3)
  'two' => &
    array
      0 => string 'sub1' (length=4)
      'twotwo' => &
        array
          0 => string 'sub1' (length=4)
          1 => string 'sub2' (length=4)
      1 => string 'sub2' (length=4)
  1 => string 'three' (length=5)
```

You can ignore the fact in the output you see `& array` in places instead of simply `array`. This signifies that in the symbol table the reference count for that particular element is > 1.

The reason for this is that `$stack` is still maintaining a reference. If you do an `unset($stack);` before returning the output, the additional references are removed and the `&`s in the output will disappear.

Comment: @PhilipSchweiger: Thanks, just updated the answer too, solved the mystery of the extra references. (good old PHP manual, teaching me things ;))

Answer (score 2):

This might be more of what you are looking for (and a little more closer to true recursion), but I didn't test it because I don't have a PHP instance to work off of at the moment

Usage:

```
$input = array(
    'one',
    '#two',
    'sub1',
    'sub2',
    '/two',
    'three'
);

$result = array();
recurse($input, $result, '', 0);
```

Steps:

1. If the position is greater than the array count, we are done.
2. If we need to go back up to root, remove tag and call again
3. If we need to go into a tag, add tag and call again
4. If we are in root, add the key and blank entry
5. If we are in a tag, add the key to the tag with a blank entry

Code:

```
function recurse($input, &$result, $tag, $position) 
{
    if($position >= count($input))
    {
        return;
    }

    if(preg_match('@\/@',$input[$position]))
    {
        recurse($input, $result, '', $position + 1);
    }
    else if (preg_match('@^#@',$input[$position])) 
    {
        $result[substr($input[$position], 1)] = array();
        recurse($input, $result, substr($input[$position], 1), $position + 1);
    }
    else if($tag == '')
    {
        $result[$input[$position]] = '';
        recurse($input, $result, $tag, $position + 1);
    }
    else
    {
        $result[$tag][$input[$position]] = '';
        recurse($input, $result, $tag, $position + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - gave you an upvote, but accepted the other anser as it managed without the $position variable

Answer (score 2):

Yes, recurse function is the way. Some advices :

- Do not include "count" functions in loops when you have not to do (your "$array" is not updated, so his size still the same from the begening to the end)
- Do not use preg_match when you have simple comparison to do.
- Use references, else you should quickly get a memory error with huge arrays used in recurse functions.

Here an other way to do what you want to :

```
<?php
function recurse(&$array, &$return = array(), &$i = 0, $limit = NULL)
{
    if(!isset($limit)){
        $limit = count($array) ;
    }
    for(;$i < $limit;$i++){
        if($array[$i]{0} == '#'){
            //opening
            $key = substr($array[$i++], 1) ;
            $return[$key] = array();
            recurse($array, $return[$key], $i, $limit) ;
        }elseif($array[$i]{0} == '/'){
            return ;
        }else{
            //same level
            $return[$array[$i]] = '';
        }
    }
}

$arr = array(
  'one',
  '#two',
  'sub1',
  '#t2',
  'sub1.1',
  'sub1.2',
  '/t2',
  'sub2',
  '/two',
  'three'
);
$nested = array();
recurse($arr, $nested);
var_dump($nested);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Off by one error

```
  $tag = str_replace('#','',$tag);
  $nested[$tag] = recurse($array, $i+1);
  $i+= count($nested[$tag])+1;
```

When you return the nested array, you have to skip over the closing tag, so it should be `$i += count($nested[$tag]) + 2;`.

Comment: Looks like that only works for one level of nesting, unfortunately. The code needs to be agnostic re levels of nesting.

Comment: Ah, right. So it's got to be references, yep, khael's answer looks very good.